# GLException: No GL context; create a Window first

Tags: python, pyglet, trimesh

I am trying to read and display a .ply file with [Trimesh](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh) in Python. I have installed Trimesh using `pip install trimesh` as well as `pyglet` to display the file.

```
import trimesh
mesh = trimesh.load("file.ply")
mesh.show()
```

However, I keep getting the following error when running this code:

```
GLException: No GL context; create a Window first
```

Could someone please help me resolve this?